# PDF that can be scanned faster by a PDF reader

Tags: pdftex, pdf, viewers, copy-paste

Searching words with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in common PDF readers takes sometimes very long.

The duration does not correlate with the number of pages, or the number of embedded pictures.

Is there a trick in (Lua/PDF)LaTeX which makes searching in the PDF files faster?

Can LaTeX for example generate an **index** that improves search functions? 
I expect that LaTeX can store the text and typographic information more or less efficient.

```
% Just a brainstorming, to illustrate what I am thinking about:
\bf{T}\bf{e}\bf{s}\bf{t} \it{text}.
\bf{Test} \it{text}.

% or even
\invisible{Test text.} %fast to parse in the pdf reader.
\bf{Test} \it{text}.   %some magic prevents the pdf reader from using this to search.
```

Comment: Does it happen the second time you open the same PDF file? (Not a copy but precisely the same file)

Comment: Does this relates specifically to files produced by `pdftex` or `xetex` or `luatex`?

Comment: It seems that it depends only on the length and complexity (figures, graphics...) of the PDF document. Then it has nothing to do with the tool used to generate PDF files and I vote to close this question as off topic.

Comment: As it's a general question regarding the PDF format, it's closed for now. It can be reopened if it would be edited to be more (La)TeX specific, for example if you add a know method to improve PDF full text search in general, and ask how to implement that in LaTeX. Just now it's unclear if there's a PDF search optimization at all.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz There seems to be one. In my Adobe Reader XI, I went to _Help, About Adobe Plug-Ins, Search_, and there it said: "The Search plug-in serves as a backend for providing search services. It also loads indexes for special documents that contain the AutoIndex key.". No idea how to use/access the _AutoIndex key_, though. Also, in my (presumably standard) installation, the plugin is not "loaded", so it might not be helpful to the majority of people. Still, a trace perhaps worth following.

Comment: Regarding the edit an hour ago: I think you should first look into the PDF format, and see whether it contains any support for indexes of the form you describe, and which is supported by the PDF readers you care about. *Then* you can ask how and whether LaTeX could generate this index, say. Otherwise your question is asking whether LaTeX can do some magic influencing the execution of your PDF viewer, without the existence of a mechanism for doing so.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I upvoted them and will try to learn more about the PDF standard first and then continue here.